# How to call/create test class for a RemoteAction

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, remote-action

This is my apex controller:

```
public with sharing class EventsController { 
        @RemoteAction
            public static ASPHPP__ASPayment_TXN__c getPaymentTXNs(Id oppID, Id eventId, ID co_id, String pbook, Opportunity opp, ID acc_id, String prod_quantity, String qps, String total2, String bookerId){
            /** Some Code **/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call it exactly as you would any other static method. First, create some sample data, then call Test.startTest(), and then call the method:

```
@isTest static void test() {
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity(...);
    insert o;
    // Keep going...
    Test.startTest();
    ASPHPP__ASPayment_TXN__c result = EventsController.getPaymentTXNs(o.Id, ...);
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertEquals(o.Id, result.Opportunity__c); // Or whatever makes sense.
}
```